# Multiple Multipvariate Time Series with LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, lstm

The dataset I am working on can be found below.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/behrad3d/nasa-cmaps/data

The data is multiple multivariate time-series data. The dataset tracks 26 features of an engine through its lifecycle until failure. It does this for 100 different engines. There is a Time Cycle feature which records the number of time cycles until failure, starting with 1. In our training set, we can subtract the max-time cycle for an engine from its current lifecycle to get RUL, Remaining Useful Lifecycles, which is the feature we will be predicting. Our test set doesn't contain the full lifecycle data of 100 engines. The model has to predict the RUL of the engine with the limited data.

The current shape of my dataset is 20631, 126 (I did feature engineering which brought me to 126 features). These 20631 rows contain a time series data for 100 engines. I know how to split them into train and test sets while maintaining the temporal order of each engine's data. But one thing to note is that the engines don't have the same number of Time_Cycles.

How should I train my LSTM such that it treats each engine as a multivariate time series, and trains the model that Ill use for predictions on all 100 engines?

Below is the code I've worked up to, but I think its training on the data as if it were all one engine. Do I need to reshape my inputs? Or add more layers?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

# split training data into train and test
train_diff = train_diff.fillna(method='backfill')
if 'RUL_pred' in test_diff.columns:
    test_diff = test_diff.drop(columns=['RUL_pred'])
test_diff = test_diff.fillna(method='backfill')

np.random.seed(42)
random_indices = np.random.choice(list(range(1,101)), size=30, replace=False)

X_train = train_diff[~train_diff['unit_number'].isin(random_indices)]
X_test = train_diff[train_diff['unit_number'].isin(random_indices)]

Y_train = X_train['RUL']
Y_test = X_test['RUL']

X_train = X_train.drop(columns=['RUL'])
X_test = X_test.drop(columns=['RUL'])

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_s = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_s = scaler.transform(X_test)
test_diff_s = scaler.transform(test_diff)

# Define LSTM model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=64, input_shape=(X_train_s.shape[1], 1)))  # Assuming X_train_s is scaled
model.add(Dense(units=1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error')

# Reshape data for LSTM input (assuming X_train_s and X_test_s are scaled)
X_train_s_lstm = np.reshape(X_train_s, (X_train_s.shape[0], X_train_s.shape[1], 1))
X_test_s_lstm = np.reshape(X_test_s, (X_test_s.shape[0], X_test_s.shape[1], 1))

# Train the LSTM model
history = model.fit(X_train_s_lstm, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

# Make predictions on test data
y_lstm_pred = model.predict(X_test_s_lstm)
```